# Failing to do gmail logout in selenium webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium

After login code of gmail through webdriver , I am trying to perform logout operation with below code- But I failed:(

```
// to get pop up of account from where I am getting sign out button to click.  
driver.findElement(By.className("gb_X gbii")).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
```

Please suggest me correct way to write down code for gmail logout in eclipse.

Note : In Eclipse console I observed below log:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector gb_X
>   gbii is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The
>   following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names
>   not permitted Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Compound names are not allowed to identify the elements in selenium. Instead search by all span tags and select the span which contains the class names as 'gb_X gbii'.

Answer (score 0):

As Sham said compound names are not allowed to identify the elements in selenium but you shouldn't search all span tags.

Use xpath instead to identify needed element directly:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'gb_X gbii')]).click();
```